# Append multiple arrays of layout constraints into single Swift array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, autolayout

How can I gather layout constraints returned by multiple calls to `constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:` into a single array? For instance, the Swift compiler flags this with error `[NSLayoutConstraint] is not identical to 'UInt8'`:

```
var newConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
newConstraints +=  NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format1, options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
```

I am using Xcode 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`constraintsWithVisualFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:) returns `[AnyObject]`. You need to cast it `[NSLayoutConstraint]` to add it to array of type `[NSLayoutConstraint]`:

```
newConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format1, options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views) 
  as [NSLayoutConstraint]
```